# Recompile a lambda to 'fix' constants

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to write code that is performant yet flexible, but have run into a snag. I have configuration that I know will not change, and so I have been building the function as a partial application of a function that includes the config. Is there any way to tell it to completely rebuild the function inserting the values as literally as possible?

I have profiled the following. `testFunc1` is our baseline.

```
"use strict";
const testFunc1 = (x)=> x+5;

const z=5;
const testFunc2 = (x)=> x+z;

const testFuncBase = (x,y)=> x+y;
const testFunc3=(x)=>testFuncBase(x,5);

const obj={y:5};
const testFunc4=(x)=>testFuncBase(x, obj.y);

const obj2={y:5};
Object.freeze(obj2);
const testFunc5=(x)=>testFuncBase(x, obj2.y);

const funcBuilder=(y)=> ((x)=>x+y);
const testFunc6=funcBuilder(5);
```

None of the others come close to `testFunc1`, yet most of them are functionally identical (`testFunc4` isn't, as `obj.y` can change). I hoped that under load the JIT would specialise the lambdas and inject constants. It doesn't seem to.
I could try grabbing the source as a string, doing string processing to inject my values, and then build that, but it would be quite messy and bug prone.

Edit: Profiling was weird, and seemed to be optimising whichever one I ran first. I'll leave this up for a bit, then delete it, as it does just seem to work if I run the tests one at a time.

Comment: How are you measuring this performance?

Comment: "*hoped that under load the JIT would specialise the lambdas and inject constants.*" - which JIT are you using? But yeah, JS engines still don't optimise functional code very well. You might want to file some feature requests - especially `testFunc2` should be easy to optimise - but I doubt you'll achieve a lot.

Comment: "*Is there any way to tell it to completely rebuild the function inserting the values as literally as possible?*" - no. "*I could try grabbing the source as a string, doing string processing to inject my values, and then build that, but it would be quite messy and bug prone.*" - yes. You'll have to arrive at `new Function("x", "return x+5;")`, and probably build an interpreter for the intermediate parts yourself.

Comment: Edited to reflect that it was a quirk from my profiling setup, and should just work. Thanks for your help, making me think more about how I was measuring it, and suggesting something new that should work as well was a great help. I was tipped off by that new function profiling badly too!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to remember Knuth's dictum: "premature optimization is the root of all evil."  Is the difference in time between `func1` and `func2` worth all the effort you've put into thinking about it?

If this function was the absolute central loop of your program, and an increase of even 1ns is going to slow your code down, then do whatever it takes. Otherwise, you're really just wasting your time optimizing the wrong thing.  I'd go with `func2()` and not give it a second thought.

Comment: `testFunc2` was never a viable option, I just included it because it was a bridge between the very raw example and `testFunc5`, which was the one I really cared about. It proved to be an artefact of my testing, but it was appearing 4-5x slower, and that wasn't ok. If it was a one line trick to tell V8 to take my closure and build a completely fresh function out of it then I absolutely would like to know that I have that option. 
Premature optimisation is a sin, but building something you want to perform without first asking if the patterns you are using are able to be performant is also dim.

Comment: Ah.  I understand.  But I repeat, unless it is critical that this function be fast, write the code that is most readable and best expresses what you need to have happen.